# I try to get the backers and the home city of different projects on kickstarter

Tags: python, selenium, dataframe, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

With the following code I try to get the home city and places where the backers are located from kickstarter. However, I keep running into the following error:

> File "D:/location", line 60, in < module >
>       page1 = urllib.request.urlopen(projects[counter])
>       IndexError: list index out of range

Does someone have a more elegant solution to feed the page to urllib.request.urlopen? (see the lines in **   **)

code:

```
# coding: utf-8 
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time 
from datetime import datetime
from collections import OrderedDict
import re

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.kickstarter.com/discover?ref=nav')
categories = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('category-container')

category_links = []
for category_link in categories:
#Each item in the list is a tuple of the category's name and its link.category_links.append((str(category_link.find_element_by_class_name('f3').text),
                     category_link.find_element_by_class_name('bg-white').get_attribute('href')))


scraped_data = []
now = datetime.now()
counter = 1

for category in category_links:
browser.get(category[1])
browser.find_element_by_class_name('sentence-open').click()
time.sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_id('category_filter').click()
time.sleep(2)

for i in range(27):
    try:
        time.sleep(2)
        browser.find_element_by_id('category_'+str(i)).click()
        time.sleep(2)            
    except:
        pass

#while True:
#   try:
#       browser.find_element_by_class_name('load_more').click()
#   except:
#       break           

projects = []
for project_link in browser.find_elements_by_class_name('clamp-3'):
    projects.append(project_link.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href'))

for project in projects:
    **page1 = urllib.request.urlopen(projects[counter])**
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page1, "lxml")
    **page2 = urllib.request.urlopen(projects[counter].split('?')**[0]+'/community')
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page2, "lxml")
    time.sleep(2)
    print(str(counter)+': '+project+'\nStatus: Started.')
    project_dict = OrderedDict()
    project_dict['Category'] = category[0]
    browser.get(project)
    project_dict['Name'] = soup1.find(class_='type-24 type-28-sm type-38-md navy-700 medium mb3').text

    project_dict['Home State'] = str(soup1.find(class_='nowrap navy-700 flex items-center medium type-12').text)

    try:
        project_dict['Backer State'] = str(soup2.find(class_='location-list-wrapper js-location-list-wrapper').text)
    except:
        pass

    print('Status: Done.')
    counter+=1
    scraped_data.append(project_dict)

later = datetime.now()
diff = later - now

print('The scraping took '+str(round(diff.seconds/60.0,2))+' minutes, and scraped '+str(len(scraped_data))+' projects.')

df = pd.DataFrame(scraped_data)
df.to_csv('kickstarter-data.csv')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only use `counter` to print the project status message, you can use `range` or `enumerate` instead. Here is an example with `enumerate`:

```
for counter, project in enumerate(projects): 
    ... code ...
```

`enumerate` produces a tuple ( index, item ) , so the rest of your code should work fine as it is.

A fiew more things:

List index starts at 0 so when you use `counter` to access items you get an `IndexError` because you initiate `counter` with 1.

In the for loop you don't need `projects[counter]`, just use `project`